# Unable to Update Join/Lookup Primary Key Contraint

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, join

I'm having an issue updating a join table properly in Entity Framework. I'm getting errors that I can't update because of primary key constraints. What's the correct way to approach this?

```
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_WEB_AUDIO'. Cannot insert
> duplicate key in object 'dbo.WEB_AUDIO'. The duplicate key value is
> (5110).
```

This is apart of a CRON job, so the AddOrUpdate is necessary.

```
using (var ctx = new WebEntities())
{
    relatedFiles.ForEach(relatedFile =>
    {
    var assocProd = ctx.WEB_VAULT_LOOKUP.SingleOrDefault(c => c.MODEL_SERIES == product.PartId);

    assocProd.WEB_AUDIO.Add(new WEB_AUDIO()
        {
            AudioID = relatedFile.ID,
            DisplayName = relatedFile.Name,
            URL = relatedFile.Path
        });
    });
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

[image: Database]

[image: Model]

Comment: At what point do you call ctx.SaveChanges()?

Comment: after the end of the foreach loop. (Updated Question.)

Comment: Can you post the key constraint exception message that you're getting?

Comment: Please don't vandalise your post. You cannot delete it because the users who have answered would lose their reputation, wasting their time. If you **really** want to delete your post, you can either raise a custom flag asking for deletion, or use the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page explaining your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you aren't duplicating that related file ID.

```
if(assocProd.WEB_AUDIO.Any(wa => wa.AudioId == relatedFile.Id)) {
   return;
}
```

That's rough, the best way would be to do a join on existing Ids and compare them in memory if the data set isn't enormous.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The error shown has nothing to do with FKs, it is PK error.

This is a data issue, you are trying to insert data that already exists in the table. That is what the PK is supposed to do, prevent duplicates. This error is a good thing, it is preventing you from creating a mess. This swhy we have such things as PKs and FKs - to prevent data integrity issues.

You might profile your insert to see if it is trying to insert the same data multiple times. (Sopmetimes people have an accidental loop) Or you might change the insert query to make sure the record doesn't already exist. Or you might have race conditions where two users are trying to insert the same information or where users aren't properly looking up the information before they try to insert it. All of these problems would have different solutions, you need to know exactly why it is sending the same record more than once.

If you have an FK error you haven't shown us, then likely you are trying to insert in the wrong order. Parent tables need to be inserted to before child tables.

Comment: You're right, it is a Primary key.
I'm looking for the way to construct the proper query to make sure the record doesn't already exist.